# How to convert a html page to a vue page?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to convert the html page seen below to a vue.js file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Process</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;

}

/* Header/Logo Title */
 .header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  display:flex; 
} 
.header1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
} 
.element1{
  justify-content: left; align-items: left
} */


.element2 {
  justify-content: right; align-items: right;
}
/* Page Content */
.content {padding:20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body class="body">

<div class="header">
  <div>
      <h1 >File List</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left: 800px; margin: 15px;">
      <button style="display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="createFolder()" >Create New Folder</button>
  </div>
 <div style="margin: 15px;">
    <button style="display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="location.href='./workfloweditor.html'" >Create New Process</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="header1" ></div>

<script>
  axios.get('http://139.59.72.204:8080/wz/getAllProcess').then(resp => {
                    datas = resp.data;
          console.log(datas)
          getfile(datas)
        })
  var data = {}
  function getfile(datas){
    for(var i = 0; i< datas.length; i++){
                            // create its value
                        bata = datas[i];
                        var pro = bata.processDetails
                        var potu = JSON.parse(pro)
                        data[potu.processName] = potu.processDetails
          }

              var mydiv = document.getElementById("demo"); 
              for(var k in data){
                                if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)){ 
              for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
              var row = document.createElement("div"); 
              row.className = "row";
              row.style = "padding-left: 40px"

                        var cell = document.createElement("a"); 
                        cell.href = "./workfloweditor.html"
                        var img = document.createElement("img")
                        img.src = "images/xmlss.png"
                        img.align = "left"
                        img.hspace= "8"
                        cell.innerText = k
                        cell.appendChild(img)
                        row.appendChild(cell); 
                        }
                        mydiv.appendChild(row);
                      }
                    }


  }
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
    console.log(target.innerText) 
    for(var k in data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        if(target.innerText == k){
          localStorage.setItem("data",data[k])
          localStorage.setItem("key",k)
        }
        if(target.innerText == "Create New Process"){
          localStorage.removeItem("data")
          localStorage.removeItem("key")
        }
      }
    } 
}, false);      
</script>
<script>
  function createFolder(){
    var divs = document.getElementById("demo")
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
              var row = document.createElement("div"); 
              row.className = "row";
              row.style = "padding-left: 40px"

                        var cell = document.createElement("a"); 
                        cell.href = "./new.html"
                        var img = document.createElement("img")
                        var inp = document.createElement("input")
                        inp.id = "inputs"
                        inp.type = "text"
                        inp.placeholder = "Enter Name"
                        inp.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var t = document.getElementById("inputs").value;
                              var node = document.getElementById("inputs")
                              var x = document.createElement("span")
                              x.innerText = t
                              cell.appendChild(x)
                              row.removeChild(node)
                            }
                        });
                        img.src = "images/folders.png"
                        img.align = "left"
                        img.hspace= "8"
                        cell.appendChild(img)
                        row.appendChild(inp)
                        row.appendChild(cell); 

                        }
                        divs.appendChild(row)
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i rewrite this in vue.js?

What i have tried so far-

```
<template>
<div class="header">
  <div>
      <h1 >File List</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left: 800px; margin: 15px;">
      <button style="display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="createFolder()" >Create New Folder</button>
  </div>
 <div style="margin: 15px;">
    <!-- <button style="display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;" type="button" onclick="location.href='./workfloweditor.html'" >Create New Process</button> -->
    <b-field>
          <b-button @click="$router.push({name: 'processmodels', params:{id:null}})" class="is-radiusless">Create New Process</b-button>
        </b-field>
 </div>
</div>

</template>

<style>
/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;

}

/* Header/Logo Title */
 .header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  display:flex; 
} 
.header1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
} 
.element1{
  justify-content: left; align-items: left
} */

.element2 {
  justify-content: right; align-items: right;
}
/* Page Content */
.content {padding:20px;}
</style>

<script>
const ViewName = 'process'
export default {
  name: 'process',
  data () {
    return {
      searchValue: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    viewData () {
      return this.$store.getters.getViewData(ViewName)
    },
    objectData () {
      return this.$store.getters.getApiData('api_process').data
    },
    sessionData () {
      return this.$store.getters.getSessionData()
    },
    isLoading () {
      return this.$store.getters.getApiData('api_process').isLoading
    },
    filteredEmployeeList () {
      if (this.objectData.length > 0) {
        return this.objectData.filter(option => {
          return (option.id + option.firstName + option.lastName)
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase())
        })
      } else {
        return this.objectData
      }
    }
  },
  beforeCreate () {
    this.$store.dispatch('setDataArray', {
      key: this.$store.state.contextData.viewData[ViewName].api_id,
      data: []
    })
  },
  mounted () {

     require('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')

     axios.get('http://139.59.72.204:8080/wz/getAllProcess').then(resp => {
                    datas = resp.data;
          console.log(datas)
          getfile(datas)
           })  
  },
  methods: {

         getfile(datas){
    for(var i = 0; i< datas.length; i++){
                            // create its value
                        bata = datas[i];
                        var pro = bata.processDetails
                        var potu = JSON.parse(pro)
                        data[potu.processName] = potu.processDetails
          }

              var mydiv = document.getElementById("demo"); 
              for(var k in data){
                                if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)){ 
              for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
              var row = document.createElement("div"); 
              row.className = "row";
              row.style = "padding-left: 40px"

                        var cell = document.createElement("a"); 
                        cell.href = "./workfloweditor.html"
                        var img = document.createElement("img")
                        img.src = "images/xmlss.png"
                        img.align = "left"
                        img.hspace= "8"
                        cell.innerText = k
                        cell.appendChild(img)
                        row.appendChild(cell); 
                        }
                        mydiv.appendChild(row);
                      }
                    }


  },

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText; 
    console.log(target.innerText) 
    for(var k in data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        if(target.innerText == k){
          localStorage.setItem("data",data[k]) //passing xml data
          localStorage.setItem("key",k)
        }
        if(target.innerText == "Create New Process"){
          localStorage.removeItem("data")
          localStorage.removeItem("key")
        }
      }
    } 
}, false),
    selected (item) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'client', params: { id: item.id } })
    }
  },
  components: {}
}
</script>
```

I dont know how to rewrite the document.addEventListener('click', function part and the axios.get() part of it in the mounted function in the vue js?. Plz help me rewrite this in the vue format and also mention if there are any other changes that i have to make in my vue file.

Comment: This question is way too big. Please create specific questions about each thing that you get stuck on, if you cannot solve them.

Comment: i just wanted to know how i can rewrite the html script in the vue file inside the mounted function.It would be helpful if you can tell me how to rewrite only the document.addEventListener('click', function(e) and not the entire thing

Comment: To convert the `document.addEventListener` function to Vue, use `@click="myMethod"` in the corresponding tag, and put the rest of the code (with the appropriate minor changes) inside the `myMethod` function.

Comment: ok this works!! thank you

Comment: now there is only one error left in the console saying 'Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getfile is not defined'

Comment: getfile() is currently defined inside the methods: section and the function call is made after the axios.get statement

Comment: is there anything wrong with the placement of the method ?

Comment: or should i put the function inside mounted: section instead?